# How to see the analysis flow of cppdepend (eg. for base class should not use derivatives)

Tags: c++, cppdepend

Im playing around with cppdepend,
 and one thing bugs me:
It lists certain classes that violate "base class should not use derivatives". But I didnt figure out a way to see exactly where and how base class is using derivatives. 
Can it be done?
BTW im using evaluation version on Win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check what methods used from base class ,the easy way is to select the base class concerned in the class browser,righ click and choose "Select Methods That I Use" , you will have also methods existing in derivative classes.

Comment: meh nevermind... I gave up, I have a ton of code and from what I see calling Base ctor in Der init list makes the classes mutually dependent. BS. When I saw that warning I was expecting something super weird, not this since it is one way dependance.